# How to get reports from Jira?

Tags: testing, jira, manual-testing

I just want to create report from Jira (Chart report showing total bugs of weekly report for 2 projects) I tried using time since report.Generated graph displayed total bugs for the 2 projects, But I want 2 projects name with each issues associated with project for each day.Is there any way to get the report?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are in search of a Dashboard. Dashboard will keep you update after regular interval about the status of the project. For creation of a dashboard you will need to create a filter first and then the Dashboard.

1. Create filter according to your requirements. i.e. search issues logged by QA in particular time period, in particular sprint etc.
   This link will help you https://university.atlassian.com/uac/2.0/courses/end-user/jira/v60/search-and-filters/save-and-share-filter#/lesson-content-header
2. After creation of the Filter create a dashboard. 
   Follow steps mentioned in below link https://university.atlassian.com/uac/2.0/courses/end-user/jira/v60/dashboards/create-share-customize-a-dashboard
   https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Customizing+the+Dashboard

Hope this helps you.